# Parsing Multiple Data Occurrences Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

```
Basic Example Text File:
    World
    start 1:00pm
    people = 1
    candy = 20
    water = 30
    school = 40
    end 2:00pm

    World
    start 3:00pm
    people = 3
    candy = 50
    water = 60
    school = 70
    end 4:00pm
```

I have a text file as such with complex data and values. For some reason my currency program works for the first search(job1) but not for the second search(job2). Can someone help me figure out the issue i'm not seeing in my code please.

```
import pprint
import re


def field_Extract(fileLine, fieldsArray, delimit):
    for field in fieldsArray:
        if field in fileLine:
            key, value = fileLine.split(delimit)
            print(key.rstrip(), " : ", value.strip())


test_file = open('/Desktop/BRRS_test file.txt', 'r+')
# setup field name for report
job1 = ['NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS', 'RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE', 'RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE',
        'COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION',
        'COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION', 'ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION', 'ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION',
        'PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS']
job2 = ['6010 TOTAL DELIVERY RECORDS READ', '6050 TOTAL ERROR RECORDS WRITTEN',
        '7025 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED', '7035 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS UPDATED',
        '7027 TOTAL ACC DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED', '7030 TOTAL DELIVERY ROWS UPDATED', 'SHIPPER DEFAULT ZON',
        'SLI INVALID FOR SAT', 'COUNTS FOR COUNTRY',
        'RECORDS READ', 'ERRORS WRITTEN', 'TKPUGPD INSERTED', 'TPKGUPD UPDATED', 'TACCUPD INSERTED',
        'CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN', 'ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS']
# setup field name for report
# -----------------------------
# setup start and end string
job1_start = 'BEGINNING N260RV30'
job1_end = 'END OF    N260RV30'
job2_start = 'PROGRAM N260CV10 BEGINNING'
job2_end = 'SUCCESSFUL END N260CV10'
# setup start and end string
start_point = False
search_point = job1_start
end_point = job1_end
job = job1
for line in test_file:
    if search_point in line:  # establish the starting point based on search qualifier
        start_point = True
    if start_point:
        if (end_point in line):
            print('########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########')
            start_point = False
            # establish new start_point - read next line
            for line in test_file:
                # verify if current job has multiple report/version & set pointer
                if job1_start in line:
                    search_point = job1_start
                    end_point = job1_end
                    job = job1
                    start_point = True
                    break
                # --------------------------------------------------------------
                # verify whether any subsequent job in report file & set pointer
                # NEED TO BE in a loop to LOOK thru' all jobs to set start point
                # --------------------------------------------------------------
                elif job2_start in line:
                    search_point = job2_start
                    end_point = job2_end
                    job = job2
                    start_point = True
                    break
        else:
            field_Extract(line, job, ':')
```

Output

```
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,928
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,790
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  138
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  13
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  16
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,980
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,814
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  166
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  29
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  39
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,681
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,547
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  134
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  19
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  19
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  10,241
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  10,078
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  163
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  37
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  23
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,748
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,597
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  151
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  13
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  16
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  10,106
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,919
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  187
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  21
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  28
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,796
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,664
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  132
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  15
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  16
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  10,252
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  10,081
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  171
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  30
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  31
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  9,607
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,449
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  158
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  8
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  13
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
NUMBER OF INPUT RECORDS  :  10,145
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ADJUSTMENT FILE  :  9,966
RECORDS WRITTEN TO ERROR FILE  :  179
COD RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  35
COD RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
ADS RECORDS PASSED CEV VALIDATION  :  36
ADS RECORDS FAILED CEV VALIDATION  :  0
PAR ACCESSORIAL REFUND RECORDS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
6010 TOTAL DELIVERY RECORDS READ  :  395,800
6010 TOTAL DELIVERY RECORDS READ  :  395,800
6050 TOTAL ERROR RECORDS WRITTEN  :  313
7025 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED  :  395,568
7035 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS UPDATED  :  232
7027 TOTAL ACC DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED  :  431,625
7030 TOTAL DELIVERY ROWS UPDATED  :  177
     SHIPPER DEFAULT ZONE  :  33,698
     SLI INVALID FOR SAT  :  509
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  CA
 RECORDS READ  :  14,167
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  7
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  14,167
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  2,115
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  6
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  1
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  US
 RECORDS READ  :  381,633
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  306
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  381,401
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  232
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  429,510
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  121
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  2
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########
6010 TOTAL DELIVERY RECORDS READ  :  62,166
6010 TOTAL DELIVERY RECORDS READ  :  62,166
6050 TOTAL ERROR RECORDS WRITTEN  :  240
7025 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED  :  62,166
7035 TOTAL PKG DERIVED DATA ROWS UPDATED  :  0
7027 TOTAL ACC DERIVED DATA ROWS INSERTED  :  10,714
7030 TOTAL DELIVERY ROWS UPDATED  :  174
     SHIPPER DEFAULT ZONE  :  9,140
     SLI INVALID FOR SAT  :  17
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  AT
 RECORDS READ  :  272
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  272
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  25
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  AU
 RECORDS READ  :  78
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  78
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  1
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  BE
 RECORDS READ  :  1,460
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  1,460
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  353
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  13
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  CH
 RECORDS READ  :  59
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  59
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  11
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  CN
 RECORDS READ  :  2,225
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  139
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  2,225
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  315
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  8
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  CZ
 RECORDS READ  :  64
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  64
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  13
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  DE
 RECORDS READ  :  30,065
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  27
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  30,065
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  4,209
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  76
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  DK
 RECORDS READ  :  427
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  427
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  32
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  ES
 RECORDS READ  :  639
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  639
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  230
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  FI
 RECORDS READ  :  72
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  72
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  57
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  FR
 RECORDS READ  :  3,084
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  2
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  3,084
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  426
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  4
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  GB
 RECORDS READ  :  9,636
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  24
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  9,636
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  2,152
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  47
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  11
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  HK
 RECORDS READ  :  402
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  3
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  402
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  34
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  3
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  HU
 RECORDS READ  :  141
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  141
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  11
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  ID
 RECORDS READ  :  25
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  25
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  0
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  IE
 RECORDS READ  :  66
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  66
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  10
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  IN
 RECORDS READ  :  240
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  8
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  240
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  9
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  IT
 RECORDS READ  :  3,790
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  14
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  3,790
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  1,007
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  8
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  JP
 RECORDS READ  :  246
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  246
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  4
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  KR
 RECORDS READ  :  100
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  100
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  3
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  MO
 RECORDS READ  :  4
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  4
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  1
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  MX
 RECORDS READ  :  1,824
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  4
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  1,824
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  258
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  MY
 RECORDS READ  :  300
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  2
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  300
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  5
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  2
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  NL
 RECORDS READ  :  3,730
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  3,730
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  385
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  NO
 RECORDS READ  :  47
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  47
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  12
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  PH
 RECORDS READ  :  116
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  2
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  116
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  20
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  2
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  PL
 RECORDS READ  :  2,111
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  2,111
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  958
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  PT
 RECORDS READ  :  39
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  39
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  5
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  SE
 RECORDS READ  :  399
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  399
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  123
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  2
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  SG
 RECORDS READ  :  136
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  0
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  136
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  17
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  0
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  TH
 RECORDS READ  :  109
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  109
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  8
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  TW
 RECORDS READ  :  159
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  4
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  159
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  18
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  4
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
 COUNTS FOR COUNTRY  :  VN
 RECORDS READ  :  101
 ERRORS WRITTEN  :  1
  TKPUGPD INSERTED  :  101
  TPKGUPD UPDATED  :  0
  TACCUPD INSERTED  :  2
 CEV ASY DROP & WRITTEN  :  1
 ZONE NOT FOUND ERRORS  :  0
########============ NEW JOB STARTS HERE ===========#########

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: how exactly does it _not work_?

Comment: There is way too much code to read, pleas read the guidelines on how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is happening because of the way file iterators work. Once you've read all the lines in the file, you need to close the file and open it again to read its contents a second time. I'd recommend parsing the entire file into some usable in-memory data structure (depending on the filesize, of course) to do your computations. Else, loop over each job, and open/close your file within the loop